# Java animation rotating and moving objects

Tags: java, swing, animation, graphics2d, affinetransform

I have a little problem with my program in Java. I want to display an animation of a rolling circle, and that circle has a stick on the edge and on this stick is smaller circle is moving from `endOfTheStick` to `contactPoint` and back again. The problem is with moving this smaller circle.

[image: Problem picture]

These functions draw me a rotating circle, a stick on the edge of the circle and a small circle at the end of the stick:

```
    private void doDrawing(Graphics g) {
        Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D) g.create();

        // Drawing slippery slope
        g2d.drawPolygon(polyX, polyY, 3);

        // Set start position
        g2d.translate(50-r1/2, startY-r1);
        g2d.rotate(polyAngle, r1/2, r1);

        /* Drawing circle
            x-value of shift
        */
        g2d.translate(x, 0);
        g2d.rotate(rotateAngle, r1/2, r1/2);
        g2d.drawOval(0, 0, r1, r1);
        g2d.drawLine(0, r1/2, r1, r1/2);
        g2d.drawLine(r1/2, 0, r1/2, r1);

        //Rotating stick
        AffineTransform.getRotateInstance(speedStickAngle, stickContact[0], stickContact[1]).transform(stickEnd, 0, stickEnd, 0, 1);
        g2d.drawLine(stickContact[0], stickContact[1], (int)stickEnd[0], (int)stickEnd[1]);

        //Rotating and moving small circle
        AffineTransform.getRotateInstance(speedStickAngle, stickContact[0], stickContact[1]).transform(centerOfSmallCircle, 0, centerOfSmallCircle, 0, 1);
        g2d.drawOval((int)centerOfSmallCircle[0]-r2/2, (int)centerOfSmallCircle[1]-r2/2, r2, r2);
    }

    @Override
    public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {

        super.paintComponent(g);
        doDrawing(g);
        tm.start();
    }

    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){
        if(x<0||x>(getWidth())){
            xSpeed =- xSpeed;
            speedAngle =- speedAngle;
            speedStickAngle =- speedStickAngle;
        }
        x = x + xSpeed;
        rotateAngle = rotateAngle + speedAngle;
        repaint();
    }
}
```

Comment: here is some useful information about the matrix stack which is crucial to understanding movements in graphics https://www.processing.org/tutorials/transform2d/

Comment: The code is not balanced: There are five `}`s and four `{`. Have you left something out in the beginning?

Comment: He left the class declaration.

Comment: Hint: transformations are compounding.  Personally, I'd still generate a single image at a "known" position and then rotate the larger circle, but that's because my brain can't take all that transformations ;)

Comment: #user3703028 you are not getting anywhere with this I 'm surprised you even got a bit out  of this - if you re willing to abandon the graphics.translate and stuff I'd be willing to assist you - but its a big project